# Comparing proportions in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `df` like this one:

```
Id    Var1    Var2    Var3
001   yes     no      yes
002   no      no      yes
003   yes     yes     no
```

I want to create a barplot with 3 bars that represents proportions of `yes`and `no`for `Var1` `Var2` `Var3`. Is it possible to do that with `ggplot`without reshaping the dataframe?

Thank you,

corrado

Comment: yes, but reshaping is more flexible and will save you typing.

Comment: In your opinion what is the best way to reshaping this dataframe in order to obtain the plot I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already mentioned it is better to reshape data.

But if you need to use original data frame then you should use `geom_bar()` for each column you want to appear on plot. In `geom_bar()` you should provide `x` values that will separate those bars - I used variable names as characters. `fill=` and `position="stack"` ensures that bars are stacked. `y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))` will calculate proportions.

```
df <- read.table(text=
"Id    Var1    Var2    Var3
 001   yes     no      yes
 002   no      no      yes
 003   yes     yes     no",header=T)

library(scales)
library(ggplot2
ggplot(df)+
  geom_bar(aes(x="Val1",fill=Var1,y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)),position="stack")+
  geom_bar(aes(x="Val2",fill=Var2,y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)),position="stack")+
  geom_bar(aes(x="Val3",fill=Var3,y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)),position="stack")+
  scale_y_continuous("Percents",labels = percent) + 
  scale_x_discrete("Values")+
  scale_fill_discrete("Legend_title")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it not possible to use geom_bar(position="fill")?